# how to make links for words in telegram bot?

Tags: php, telegram, php-telegram-bot

I wanted to make a url for the words in telegram bot.
Used this code but it doesn't work:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot$botToken/sendMessage?chat_id=chat_id&text=<a href="url.com">the word</a>
```

how to make link for the words. when the user clicks on the word, he will go to the url adress page

Comment: Can you explain your question.. more precisely what do you want

Comment: sure, if you want to create a link for any word you just use this code in html `<a href="url.com">WORD</a>`. i want to create a link for the message of telegram bot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you should use the **parse_mode** parameter:

```
$url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot<BOT_TOKEN>/sendMessage';
$parameters = [
    'text'       => '<a href=\'url.com\'>word</a>',
    'chat_id'    => <chat_id>,
    'parse_mode' => 'HTML'
];

echo $url . '?' . http_build_query($parameters);
```

output:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<BOT_TOKEN>/sendMessage?text=%3Ca+href%3D%27url.com%27%3Eword%3C%2Fa%3E&chat_id=<chat_id>&parse_mode=HTML
```

Comment: '$url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot316:AAGeiqA_B4G18M/sendMessage';
$chat_id = "@TweetKon";
$message = $items['text'];
$usar = $items['user']['name'];
$usaremoji = "";
$fave = $items['favorite_count'];
$faveemoji = " | ";
$br = "\n";
$linkesh= "https://twitter.com/$username";
$Channel = "@TweetKon";
$parameters = [
    'text'       => '$message.$br.$usaremoji.<a href="https://twitter.com/$usar>$usar</a>.$faveemoji.$fave.$br.$br.$Channel',
    'chat_id'    => '@TweetKon',
    'parse_mode' => 'HTML'
];
echo $url . '?' . http_build_query($parameters);'

Comment: thanks for helping. the final code is here but it didnt work

Comment: it works as well as possible i tried it :)
thanks for helping bro

Comment: but i have a problem ! it dosn't show the Variable values

Comment: what do u mean with "Variable values"?

Comment: p.s. maybe its better to remove to bot token in the comment above ^_-

Comment: sorry i cant speak English well! For example in '$Money="Number";' in this code '$Money' is variable and 'Number' is Value

Comment: php puts variable value in a string only with " quotes.

Comment: for example: $x = 5; $str = "$x is the value"; // $str will be '5 is the value'. but in case of $str = '$x is the value'; // $str will be '$x is the value'. more info - http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double

Comment: also u can use concatination: $str = $x . ' is the value'; // $str will be '5 is the value'

Comment: UMM i didn'd undrestand ! could you please put these codes in your first code?!

Comment: i practiced and it works as well as possible ... thanks for helping. youre the best