# How to send a hyperlink in bot.sendMessage()

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telepot

My bot sends out links. so I wanted to include a hyperlink like the one you can do with HTML for example `-a href="google.com" Google /a` shows up a click able text called "Google" how can I do this in `bot.sendMessage()`? and also if you have any idea of sending bold font messages too..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to make links for words in telegram bot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41345254/how-to-make-links-for-words-in-telegram-bot)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [formatting option](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#formatting-options) to do this.

Answer (score 17):

By specifying `parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML` in send_message() you can use HTML tags.

Example for Hyperlink

```
bot.send_message(chat_id = update.message.chat_id, text = "<a href='https://www.google.com/'>Google</a>", parse_mode = ParseMode.HTML)
```

Example for Bold

```
bot.send_message(chat_id = update.message.chat_id, text = "<b>Bold font</b>", parse_mode = ParseMode.HTML)
```

For more formatting options refer [**here**](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#html-style)