# How to send text sms from telegram bot

Tags: sms, telegram, telegram-bot

reference =>  http://bradorego.com/test/sms.html

as the above reference, we can send a specific text to a specific number in mobiles, so I want to know how to do that in telegram bot chats / or messages?

we have parse_mode in sendMessage method of telegram bot, but

```
<a href="sms://+15552345678;?&body=Hello"> Send Message </a>
```

doesn't work in telegram chat

thanks

Comment: I don't kwow what you mean by "doesn't work" but take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45268368/how-to-send-a-hyperlink-in-bot-sendmessage just in case it helps you to send a valid link.